# Creating and using database : Android

Tags: java, android, database

I am working on an app, which has several modules. 
I will have to access same database in many modules multiple times.

My question is Which place is the best way and best place to create the database and tables for it??

Like...

```
    1. creating the required databases and tables at once while loading app or

    2. Creating db and tables in respective modules when required??
     resulting in extra lines of codes to check if db and table already 
     exists or not..
```

Which one is good option?? or is there other better way?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the db only within your app then I think the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) is the best choice. It will create the table the first time when you use it. (It is suggested that you make your own helper a singleton class to avoid concurrent access issue).

If you are sharing the db among two or more apps then you should wrap the db behind a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html).

Comment: that was quick! :)
Thanks a lot for the reply :)

I never knew about this class! will do research on it and try learning more about it. :)

Answer (score 3):

First you should make a class to create a DB Like :

```
package com.DB;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback;

public class DatabaseHandler_Dashboard extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dashboard";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_dashboard";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String RANK = "RANK";
    private static final String MHBHUBCD = "MHBHUBCD";
    private static final String WK1Dkts = "WK1Dkts";
    private static final String WK1Per = "WK1Per";
    private static final String WK1OnTime = "WK1OnTime";

    private static final String WK2Dkts = "WK2Dkts";    
    private static final String Wk2Per = "Wk2Per";
    private static final String WK2OnTime = "WK2OnTime";

    private static final String QTDDkts = "QTDDkts";
    private static final String QTDPer = "QTDPer";
    private static final String QTDOnTime = "QTDOnTime";

    private static final String YTDDkts = "YTDDkts";
    private static final String YTDPer = "YTDPer";
    private static final String YTDOnTime = "YTDOnTime";



    public DatabaseHandler_Dashboard(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String CREATE_DEVICE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + RANK + " TEXT,"
        + MHBHUBCD + " TEXT,"
        + WK1Dkts + " TEXT,"
        + WK1Per + " TEXT,"
        + WK1OnTime + " TEXT,"

        + WK2Dkts + " TEXT,"
        + Wk2Per + " TEXT,"
        + WK2OnTime + " TEXT,"

        + QTDDkts + " TEXT,"
        + QTDPer + " TEXT,"
        + QTDOnTime + " TEXT,"

        + YTDDkts + " TEXT,"
        + YTDPer + " TEXT,"
        + YTDOnTime + " TEXT"
        + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DEVICE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new Device
    public void addDevice(Contact_Dashboard device) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(RANK , device.get_RANK());

        values.put(MHBHUBCD  , device.get_MHBHUBCD ()); 

        values.put(WK1Dkts  , device.get_WK1Dkts()); 
        values.put(WK1Per  , device.get_WK1Per()); 
        values.put(WK1OnTime  , device.get_WK1OnTime()); 

        values.put(WK2Dkts  , device.get_WK2Dkts()); 
        values.put(Wk2Per   , device.get_Wk2Per()); 
        values.put(WK2OnTime  , device.get_WK2OnTime()); 

        values.put(QTDDkts  , device.get_QTDDkts()); 
        values.put(QTDPer  , device.get_QTDPer()); 
        values.put(QTDOnTime  , device.get_QTDOnTime()); 

        values.put(YTDDkts   , device.get_YTDDkts()); 
        values.put(YTDPer   , device.get_YTDPer()); 
        values.put(YTDOnTime   , device.get_YTDOnTime()); 


        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }





    // Getting All Devices
    public List<Contact_Dashboard> getAllDevice() {
        List<Contact_Dashboard> deviceList = new ArrayList<Contact_Dashboard>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor !=null)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Contact_Dashboard device = new Contact_Dashboard();

                    device.set_RANK(cursor.getString(0));
                    device.set_MHBHUBCD(cursor.getString(1));

                    device.set_WK1Dkts(cursor.getString(2));
                    device.set_WK1Per (cursor.getString(3));
                    device.set_WK1OnTime (cursor.getString(4));


                    device.set_WK2Dkts (cursor.getString(5));
                    device.set_Wk2Per  (cursor.getString(6));
                    device.set_WK2OnTime (cursor.getString(7));

                    device.set_QTDDkts (cursor.getString(8));
                    device.set_QTDPer (cursor.getString(9));
                    device.set_QTDOnTime (cursor.getString(10));


                    device.set_YTDDkts (cursor.getString(11));
                    device.set_YTDPer (cursor.getString(12));
                    device.set_YTDOnTime (cursor.getString(13));


                    // Adding Device to list
                    deviceList.add(device);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

    }
        cursor.close();
        return deviceList;


}





    // Getting contacts Count
    public int get_all_data() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }



    public int del_all_data()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);

    }



    // Getting All Devices
    public List<Contact_Dashboard> getAllDevice_sort_by(String vall,String sort_type)
    {
        List<Contact_Dashboard> deviceList = new ArrayList<Contact_Dashboard>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME  + " order by CAST(" + vall + " as integer)" + sort_type;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor !=null)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Contact_Dashboard device = new Contact_Dashboard();

                    device.set_RANK(cursor.getString(0));
                    device.set_MHBHUBCD(cursor.getString(1));

                    device.set_WK1Dkts(cursor.getString(2));
                    device.set_WK1Per (cursor.getString(3));
                    device.set_WK1OnTime (cursor.getString(4));


                    device.set_WK2Dkts (cursor.getString(5));
                    device.set_Wk2Per  (cursor.getString(6));
                    device.set_WK2OnTime (cursor.getString(7));

                    device.set_QTDDkts (cursor.getString(8));
                    device.set_QTDPer (cursor.getString(9));
                    device.set_QTDOnTime (cursor.getString(10));


                    device.set_YTDDkts (cursor.getString(11));
                    device.set_YTDPer (cursor.getString(12));
                    device.set_YTDOnTime (cursor.getString(13));


                    // Adding Device to list
                    deviceList.add(device);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

    }
        cursor.close();
        return deviceList;


}


}
```

Now in your other Activity page make an object of this class like :

```
DatabaseHandler_Dashboard ECDS_DB = new DatabaseHandler_Dashboard(this);
```

so automaticaly when that activity run, at that time it makes your DB and also check for DB exist or not....

Now you can make a get set method of your variable & use the DB class object in every activity like :

```
ECDS_DB.del_all_data();

    ECDS_DB.addDevice(new Contact_Dashboard(
                        ARR_RANK[i] ,
                        ARR_MHBHUBCD[i] , 

                        ARR_WK1Dkts[i] ,
                        ARR_WK1OnTime[i] ,
                        ARR_WK1Per[i] ,

                        ARR_WK2Dkts[i] ,
                        ARR_WK2OnTime[i] ,
                        ARR_Wk2Per[i] , 

                        ARR_QTDDkts[i] , 
                        ARR_QTDOnTime[i] ,
                        ARR_QTDPer[i] ,

                        ARR_YTDDkts[i] ,
                        ARR_YTDOnTime[i] ,
                        ARR_YTDPer[i] ));
```

try this & don't forget to review me...............

Comment: thanks a lot and +1 for quick reply and detailed example :)

It'll be very much helpful for me.
I'll try this out and get back here soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to use a helper class for database access, follow following steps to define a database helper:

1. Create a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.
2. Override onCreate(), onUpgrade() methods, and Constructor.
3. in onCreate() create all the tables once, so you dont need to worry about table existance later.
4. in onUpgrade() method, drop all the tables, and execute onCreate() method.
5. in your activities and services, whereever you need to access database, just create an instance of DatabaseHelper, and it will create all the tables if it is first call for database.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeet's answer is perfect but still I add this for **performance** tuning.
If your app has more no. of tables then You should create your DB in any sqlDev tool and export it in sql file. And put that into asset folder.

Now,

Create a new class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.
Check existance of your DB on device in onCreate() method. 
If your db is not available then copy your DB structure file to this path.

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/
```

By doing this, you are copying whole DB and its approximate 10 times faster than you create all tables by query one by one.